# std::regex undefined behavior

Tags: c++, regex, std

Сould anyone please describe such behavior of std::regex library

```
string a{"ERROR"};
regex r1{"errOR",0};
cout<<regex_search(a,r1)<<endl;
regex r2{"errOR"};
cout<<regex_search(a,r2)<<endl;
regex r3{"errOR",regex::ECMAScript};
cout<<regex_search(a,r3)<<endl;

cout<<r1.flags()<<endl;
cout<<r2.flags()<<endl;
cout<<r3.flags()<<endl;
```

gives output

```
1
0
0
16
16
16
```

so 1st example became implicitly ignore casing with sum of flags corresponding to default construction of re i.e 16, 
by the way in std::regex there is no constant that match 0 value,
but there is regex::icase == 1;

Is that conceived behavior of std library or I should not to feed to constructor values that explicitly not supported?

Comment: Flag values have names. Use them.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is documented what happens if you don't use a proper flag but you should assume nothing good will happen.

Comment: the values of the flags are unspecified (see eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type)), but I doubt there is undefined behaviour, anyhow of course you should not pass parameter when they are "explicitily not supported"

Comment: "by the way in std::regex there is no constant that match 0 value, but there is regex::icase == 1;" where did you take this from?

Comment: cout<<regex::icase;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::regex` has [several constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/). Two of them are:

- `explicit basic_regex (const charT* str, flag_type flags = ECMAScript);`
- `basic_regex (const charT* str, size_t len, flag_type flags = ECMAScript);`

The first constructor allows to construct the regex using a null terminated 
string. The second constructor allows to construct the regex using an array 
of characters and the array length.

The line: `regex r1{"errOR",0};` uses the second one. So, you are not using 
zero for the flags but for the string length. As `regex_search` is able to 
match your empty string, it returns `true`.

You can modify your experiment to force the first constructor using:

```
regex r1{ "errOR", regex_constants::syntax_option_type(0) };
```

The standard states that:

> A valid value of type syntax_option_type shall have at most one of the
>   grammar elements ECMAScript, basic, extended, awk, grep, egrep, set.
>   If no grammar element is set, the default grammar is ECMAScript.

So, now it is using ECMASScript and value returned by `regex_search` is 
`false`.

Regarding your last question, I would try to not use an unsupported 
parameter, because the standandard also states [defns.undefined]:

> Undeﬁned behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits 
>   any explicit deﬁnition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous 
>   construct or erroneous data.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer!